# How to pass variables into link path within l() function?

Tags: 7, navigation

I am wondering how to pass variables into a the path argument for a link created with `l()`. The path looks like `registration-history/listing/$node->nid/$sku/$node->created/$start_date` And the link text is in `$registration_count`.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This is a plain PHP question, since it is asking _How do I pass `"registration-history/listing/$node->nid/$sku/$node->created/$start_date"` and `$registration_count` to `l()`?_ If the question is more related to Drupal, please rewrite to make it a Drupal question.

Comment: I think this is a fair question for someone unfamiliar with `l()`, and what the proper usage is when the path parts are variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some Examples

**Example 1: Link to front page**

```
<?php
// example 1:  front page
print l(t('Home'), '<front>'); 
?>
```

**Example 2: Link to front page and open in new window**

```
<?php
print l(t('Home'), '<front>',array('attributes'=>array('target'=>'blank'))); 
?>
```

**Example 3: How to use html**

```
<?php
print l('<span class="front">Home</span>', '<front>',array('html' => TRUE)); 
?>
```

**Example 4: How to use image instead of text link**

Lets create my picture path

```
<?php 
global $base_url;
$path = "$base_url/sites/default/files/ceo5.png";
print l('<img src="'.$path.'" alt="Webemania CEO Image" />', 'sites/default/files/ceo5.png', array('html' => TRUE));
?>
```

**Example 5: Add class, ids, etc**

```
<?php
// add a new class to my php ini configuration path
print l(  t('PHP ini configuration'),  'node/3',  array('attributes' =>array('class'=>'php-ini-conf', 'id'=>'phpini-conf') ));
?>
```

**Example 6: Adding query string to links**

Adding a query string to example 5

```
<?php
// adding query string on example:5
print l(  t('PHP ini configuration'),  'node/33',  array('attributes' =>array('class'=>'php-ini-conf', 'id'=>'phpini-conf'), 'query'=>array('id'=>'5','status'=>'ok') ));
?>
```

The output will be:

http://webemania.com/blog/php-ini-configuration?id=5&status=ok

**Example 7: Adding destination to query link**

```
<?php
print l(  t('edit'),  'node/'.$nid.'/edit',  array('query' => drupal_get_destination() ));
?>
```

**Example 8: Create a hash-only link (to #)**

```
<?php
print l('linktext', '', array('fragment' => ' ', 'external' => TRUE));
?>
```

**Example 9: Specific portions of a page**

Use fragment attributes Go to php ini configurations short open tag portion: PHP Short open tag

```
<?php
l(  t('PHP ini configuration'),  'node/33',  array('attributes' =>array('class'=>'php-ini-conf', 'fragment' => "php-tag")));
?>
```

**References:**

[How and why to use l() function to create links in Drupal](http://www.webemania.com/blog/how-and-why-to-use-l-function-to-create-links-in-drupal)

Comment: While this shows lots of uses of `l()` I think it doesn't really address the OP's question: what is the proper way to build up a link from a bunch of path paths, some of which are variables.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer. I've posted the way I actually solved it below, but I'm sure this answer will be helpful for other developers.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, the way I solved this question:

```
$url = "registration-history/listing/$node->nid/$sku/$node->created/$start_date";

return l(t("Link text"), $url, array('attributes' => array('nid' => 'node->nid')));
```

I don't know if this is the best way, but it works.